# Filtering Items from data tables

Tags: python

I have two datasets, one is `Product Data` which has store name, available products and their corresponding quantity, other data is `Customer Order Data` where I have customer name, products they are ordering and their respective quantities. My problem is that I have to find the stores for each customer and each product they are ordering (satisfying the quantity criteria as well).

How can I code it in Python?

**Product Data**:

[image: product]

**Customer Order Data**:

[image: customer order data]

Comment: What code have you written and where exactly are you facing issues?

Comment: Can you post your data as text please ?

Comment: data={'Store' : ['Store1','Store2'], 'Products' : ['Product1','Product2','Product3','Product4','Product5','Product6','Product7','Product8','Product9','Product1','Product2','Product3','Product4','Product5','Product6','Product7','Product8','Product9'], 'Quantity' : [10,50,30,100,40,20,15,35,85,5,10,40,150,50,30,30,10,10]}
product=pd.DataFrame(data)

Comment: data={'Customer' : ['Customer1','Customer2'], 'Products_order' : ['Product1','Product2','Product4','Product6','Product7','Product9','Product3','Product4','Product5','Product6','Product8','Product9'], 'Quantity_ordered' : [5,20,10,100,15,30,20,15,50,18,35,45]}
customer=pd.DataFrame(data)

Comment: hope this will be helpful

Comment: @supratikghosh did you check the answer below

Comment: @supratikghosh does below lines worked a expected

Answer (score 1):

In terms of excel you are looking for vlookup which is done by merging datafrmes, you can explore more about it.
Check if below lines can work for you , sample df snap is attached after code lines.

Change column names as per your need.

```
import pandas as pd

df_customer = pd.read_excel('customer.xlsx')
df_product = pd.read_excel('product.xlsx')

df = pd.merge(df_customer, df_pfoduct[['Product','Storage']], on = 'Product', how = 'left')

print(df)
```

[image]